# Callback that yields element in a Generator while computation continues elsewhere

Tags: python, asynchronous, generator, grpc, listener

I'm currently working with gRPC and Python to create a service with a bidirectional call, on which a client can request a stream of solutions computed by the server: the same connection streams are however used to exchange multiple kinds of messages.
The main idea is that the client can request a solution with a *NextMsg* on the connection to the server: the server can, in turn, ask the client for some specific information before generating a solution and sending it back.
So the control flow for to reply a *NextMsg* is the following:

- Receive the request from the client.
- Start the creation process of the solution.
- Send a message to the client for additional information and await the reply.
- Finish the computation using the received data and reply with the solution.

At the moment I'm implementing all of this in Python, and I'm trying to implement abstract classes to keep generic the actual process that creates the solution, in order to be able to create different kinds of services by simply specifying that process.
When generating the service classes from a .proto file, a method with bidirectional streams uses Flows as a message observer for both input and output. This, however, doesn't let me pass a reference to the observer through the various methods called during the solution generation to send the request for additional information and, at the same time, continue from there the computation once a reply arrives.

The skeleton of the .proto file is this:

```
service GenericPrimitiveService {
  rpc callPrimitive(stream ClientMsg) returns (stream ServerMsg) {}
}

message ClientMsg {
    oneof msg {
        string request = 1;
        string next = 2;
        ...
    }
}

message ServerMsg {
    oneof msg {
        string solution = 1;
        ...
    }
}
```

The code should look like this basically:

```
def callPrimitive(self, request_iterator, context):
        stream = None 
        for msg in request_iterator:
            if(stream == None && msg.request.IsInitialized):
                stream = primitive(msg.request)
            elif(msg.next.isInitialized)
                yield next(stream)
            else
                handleReceivedInformation(msg)

def primitive(request):
    while True:
        #send something on the Generator of the bidirectional streaming
        response = await sendRequestToClient()
        solution = elaborate(response)
        yield(solution)

@abstract
def elaborate(info)
```

When implementing the same thing in Kotlin, for example, I generated the .proto classes in Java and passed the responseObserver reference through the methods, but this doesn't seem viable in Python. I know I'm mixing async and sync programming and that may not be the best, but it's all part of the requirements of the general project. How can I resolve this pickle?

Thanks in advance for y'all help!

Comment: i read to the bottom thinking this:  _"mixing async and sync programming"_ . . .

Comment: the project might be asking for something that is illogical, since the **sync** part will always block the **async** part and passing by reference might create race conditions (which you never observed by chance, but did exist)...

Comment: I know it isn't ideal, however it is made to exploit the definition of a common interface for the server that can be used in any language to ease the job of any future Service creator... I opted for trying to accumulate all the messages into a single point that then sends them all, I'll see if that works out fine. About the race conditions there shouldn't be a problem, since I'm using ExecutorServices and also the client is not able to send concurrent requests, but I'll look into that nonetheless.

Comment: well,  often one only knows when there is a race condition when it happens (by which time it is too late). For the most part that are not edge cases, we never see it, so its fine...   Anyway,  `asyncio` and `multiprocessing` are your different options in python for this...